# APIException$FailedRequestException Cannot determine the target object for this request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to the Facebook API and the Graph API Explorer, so any help understanding the tool is appreciated. I have been through quite a bit of the Facebook developer documentation trying to understand how to register an application, create and use access tokens and using Graph API Explorer to return a data I will eventually persist for use in analytic tools.

When I execute the following using Graph API Explorer it returns a message that I can't find any information on so I can track what I'm doing wrong.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/CAMPAIGN_ID/insights

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#275) Cannot determine the target object for this request. Currently supported objects include ad account, business account and associated objects.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 275,
    "fbtrace_id": "HbrtL4oBAh9"
  }
}

When I execute the same URL in a browser:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/CAMPAIGN_ID/insights?access_token=9999999999999999999999NnIi3URfZBtORdG7J6AwUjo0zzDO2AcsUrTGXYHRKj0YI4nWPUmYbMshXsxPApAEW3xUNvtIYhYEZA5wBqRLvjL4bPN8wzKq7KiJ9Rr3VQO1Ps2M8zbFl3T38cp8rhLxeLfm3OQlZBEZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ

also returns the same error message.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to SO!  could you post your code in your question? This would help a lot.

Comment: You did replace `CAMPAIGN_ID` with an actual id though, right?

Comment: Yes I do replace the CAMPAIGN_ID with a "real" id.  I'm wondering if there isn't an authorization issue.  The access_token is generated by the Graph API Explorer is based on my Facebook account, but the campaign insights I'm interested in seeing may not allow me to view.  Where all of this is leading up to is a standalone Java application main() method that will go after ad statistics using the Ad Insight API.  For example : curl -G \
-d "action_breakdowns=action_type" \
-d "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<AD_CAMPAIGN_ID>/insights"

Comment: @ChrisJuettner did you resolve this issue ?